# How to set ulimit value permanently?

Tags: debian, ulimit

On Debian Wheezy, `ulimit -a` gives:

```
open files                      (-n) 1024
```

I add this to /etc/security/limits.conf

```
*                hard    nofile          64000
```

then reboot.

And `ulimit -a` still gives a maximum number of open files of 1024. Anyone could throw some light on it?

Comment: is this possibly a virtual host?

Comment: no, it it's a mongodb server

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Option one:**
You did not set the softlimit higher aswell.

Possible solution:

in /etc/security/limits.conf add

```
* soft nofile 2048
```

test with

```
ulimit -n 2048
```

**Option two:**
You are logged in as user and in some "config" file (profile, bashrc, something like this) the soft limit is set to a lower value.

Possible solution
   f.e. grep for ulimit in your etc folder and/or home folder.

**Warning:** Depending on the amount of files/directorys you have in there you might want to consider only specific directorys/files

ps: there are a lot of similiar question here you might want to read up.

Specially [Hard vs Soft Limit](https://serverfault.com/questions/265155/soft-limit-vs-hard-limit)

Read here for possible other solution which go more into detail
[Too Many Open Files](https://serverfault.com/questions/20387/debian-too-many-open-files?rq=1)

Comment: Actually, I was trying to set only the hard limit to 64000. So the soft limit was still on 1024. Now I tried to set a soft limit to 64000  + hard = 72000. But it didn't work. I tried also "* - nofile 64000" and I get the same result.

Comment: After having read "Too Many Open Files", I thought a kernel setting would be overriding the limits.conf settings but: "fs.file-max = 4933738"

Comment: @Icu try the answers from this one aswell:
http://serverfault.com/questions/93234/setting-ulimit-and-ubuntu-8-04?rq=1

might be related to your shell

Comment: I added 'session required pam_limits.so' to /etc/pam.d/other and common-session but it doesn't help ... As an alternative, I added a 'ulimit -n' to my init script and it works but I wonder why I can't get the correct values in my shell.

Comment: I think you meant: test with `ulimit -a`.

Answer (score 26):

There is a bug in Debian. To increase `ulimit` you need to add this into the `/etc/pam.d/common-session` file:

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

and in `/etc/security/limits.conf` add:

```
*               soft    nofile          65535
*               hard    nofile          65535
```

Then reboot the system.

Comment: no need for me to make any change to the `/etc/pam.d/common-session` file. it worked just by adding the other two lines to the `limits.conf` file :-)

Comment: You shouldn't need to reboot.

Comment: This is brutal. On debian 7 now, and this isn't working. Not sure what to do :( -- I might open a new question

Comment: Boom. `*` wildcard doesn't work for `root`. I added `root` instead of `*`, and it's working. Thank you!

Comment: @FrancescoCasula - which version of Debian was that?  Just trying to figure out if this really is a bug, and if it still exists...

Comment: @FrancescoCasula It is not working on my fedora machine, any suggestions?

Comment: @Divyanshu Kushwaha Change soft and hard limits in /etc/security/limits.conf.

Answer (score 1):

In my case of Apache on Debian 10 the above didn't help though this worked:

```
echo "APACHE_ULIMIT_MAX_FILES='ulimit -n 16384'" >> /etc/apache2/envvars
service apache2 restart
```

I checked with:

```
cat /proc/$pid/limits
```

..where `$pid` is the process ID of one of the Apache processes.